# Solve this differential equation with the initial condition y(0) = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^2  x^{2/3}$$

I am having trouble solving for the constant $C$ because I always get an undefined result.

How would I solve this?

Comment: Show your work so far--I assume you've separated the variables.

Comment: you have y(x)=0

Answer (score 1):

From your equation and initial condition, it seems that $y(x)=0$ is the only possible solution.